# can not log in and I'm tried some methods suggested in other posts

Tags: login

I got `-rw-------` on Xauthority,

and I tried

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
```

and also tried

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

Now my ubuntu is totally broken, I mean I can only see a black screen for ctrl alt f1.